# Typescript/Javascript custom pipe operator taking in more than one parameter

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, pipe

I like the concept of using pipe `|` operations as it helps to make code more readable. Although there is currently no support for it, I read an [article](https://betterprogramming.pub/functional-programming-and-the-pipe-function-in-javascript-c92833052057) which allows us to define pipe operators in javascript.

The article however assumes that each function takes in one parameter which is the result of the previous operation. I am wondering if it is possible to have some functions take in more than just the result from the previous function ?

Comment: Typically you'd use _higher-order functions_ for this, e.g. `pipe(add(4), multiplyBy(3))(2)`.

Comment: oh right.. it is something like partial functions ?

Comment: What do you mean by "*more than just the result from the previous function*"? What do you want to pass? But in any case, then it's not a pipe any more.

Comment: for example, I have 2 functions, `A(T) => T` and `B(T, param) => T`. I want to be able to pipe `A` and `B` together. Javascript's reduce function does not allow to take in more than one param. Based on what @jonrsharpe mentioned, and using the concept explained in the article, it is possible to pipe functions `A` and `B` together by using currying/partial function application.

Comment: Note this isn't [the reduce method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), which calls the callbacks with _four_ arguments, but the implementation of `pipe` itself (not included in the question).

Comment: @calveeen then just use `t => B(t, 'param')` as one of the elements in the pipe